# ValueError when using Whoosh and Django Haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm trying to set up Haystack with Whoosh but am getting this value error "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required" when I run the count method on the SearchQuerySet object in ./manage shell

```
>>> sqs.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/query.py", line 375, in count
    return len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/query.py", line 48, in __len__
    self._result_count = self.query.get_count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py", line 399, in get_count
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py", line 354, in run
    results = self.backend.search(final_query, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return func(obj, query_string, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py", line 313, in search
    return self._process_results(raw_results, start_offset, end_offset, highlight=highlight, query_string=query_string, spelling_query=spelling_query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py", line 350, in _process_results
    raw_result = dict(raw_result)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required
```

Comment: lol. yeah. I'm just trying out haystack for the first time and it looked like the easiest one to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer here https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/closed#issue/281 It turns out it was a version problem.

It works if I use these specific versions of Haystack and Whoosh

```
pip install django-haystack==1.0.1-final

easy_install "Whoosh==1.0.0.b11"
```